# Issue with running docker-compose in Teamcity

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, teamcity

My Teamcity server was deployed in docker.

I am trying to build the **asp.net core** project by using **docker-compose** command. 
Here is the code of docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  fooservice:
    image: foo/foo.api:latest
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: MyProject/Dockerfile
```

However, I am getting the error

```
Step 1/1: Docker Compose
[01:55:10][Step 1/1] Unable to find build runner 'DockerCompose'
[01:55:10][Step 1/1] Unable to find build runner 'DockerCompose'
[01:55:10][Step 1/1] Step Docker Compose failed with unexpected error
```

**Update**

> If I switch to CommandLine builder (docker-compose -f  docker-compose.yml up --no-start --build) then the following error occurs:

```
[07:20:31]Step 1/1: Command Line
[07:20:31][Step 1/1] Unable to find build runner 'simpleRunner'
[07:20:31][Step 1/1] Unable to find build runner 'simpleRunner'
[07:20:31][Step 1/1] Step Command Line failed with unexpected error
```

Comment: What is the command that you used to start teamcity server and agent?

Comment: @yamenk Teamcity server was installed via portainer, I didn't specify any custom parameters. Teamcity agent was setup by the following command: FROM jetbrains/teamcity-agent:latest
 
RUN curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.22.0/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > /usr/local/bin/docker-compose \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

Answer (score 1):

The Dockerfile you have builds on teamcity-agent and installs DockerCompose. You also need to ensure that docker is installed or accessible.

As documented in the [dockerhub page for teamcity-agent](https://hub.docker.com/r/jetbrains/teamcity-agent/), you can give the teamcity agent container access to the host docker daemon by mounting the docker socket

```
...
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
...
```

Comment: I want to use option docker in docker. Once I connected to the agent, the docker daemon was running. The source codes of project also located on the agent.